# How to create efficient data structure for memory cache in java?

Tags: java, caching, data-structures

I would like to make a data structure which its insert,remove,search are O(1).
the cache remove the least requested value among the cache. and have a given size of values.
any ideas?

I thought about tree+hash table or skiplist+hash table (the hash tables in the size of the cache).

thank you

Comment: Will it be in-memory caching or caching on a file system?

Comment: Ok. Sorry. IMHO, A simple hash table would be enough for simple applications.

Comment: if I will use hash table only,  the searching is O(1),  adding is O(1) , but when the size reaches its limit, we have to  remove some values with  O(n) action (we look for the least requested object)

Comment: There are many solutions for this, like dynamic hashing for example. No rearrangement is needed in this case when the number of values become big. see http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter11/node20.html

Answer (score 5):

Instead of designing a data structure yourself, have a look at Google Guava's [Caches](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained). Their implementation is based on a concurrent hashmap which has O(1) complexity for the operations you list above. They also have a lot of other configuration options for caches such as Time To Live and concurrency levels. These options are available via the CacheBuilder interface.